# I have a page when loaded, loads a table of images via a SQL query, I want to change the way this table works on the same page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an SQL Query (shown below) which loads images from a database with a limit of 20 images.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions LIMIT 20") or die(mysql_error());
```

Is there a way with PHP/MYSQL/HTML only to use a button or any other features to change the limit of the SQL query which loads when the page loads? As I don't want load all the images in 1 go as there is 100+ but don't know how to allow the user to 'See More' like they do on the shopping pages where they allow you to see x amount of products per page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ajax to alter the limit value of your SQL query.
Start of with a fixed value of Limit,say 20
then whenever the user clicks 'see more' increase that Limit value by a constant amount.